# Unable to create Windows VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am unable to create a Windows instance i.e. a Win-2016 server with desktop experience compute engine.

Getting below message.. is there any change in the windows+GCP policy?

"Windows VM instances are not included with the free trial. To use them, first enable billing on your account. You'll still be able to apply your free trial credits to eligible products and services."

Kindly help me understand.

Comment: You need to enable billing for your project. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account

Answer (score 1):

Google updated their Free-tier Program Coverage:
[image: Free-tier Program Coverage]

So, to use Windows VM, you must enable your billing account first:

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account

Answer (score 0):

As it seems the billing account is not associated with your project. Please link  it then it should able to solve your issue ,plus check the resources you able to access in free tier program of gcp. [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

Answer (score 0):

In addition to enabling billing for the project, at the top of the google cloud console, there must be a link appearing to enable usage of free credit. After enabling it, you can create a windows VM.

Answer (score 0):

You may have upgraded and had your billing enabled by disabled and enabled on the same project, which then activated the VM instance some how

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Billing (https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/), click on your billing account then in the "Overview" section.

[image: Current location is the box in the lower right corner that says Credits]

You have to upgrade from "Free Trial" to "Full Access", supposedly you keep you free trial credits.

I just did this myself and it finally works. We'll see if they will charge me an arm and a leg =)